# Write to usb port from android application

Tags: android, serial-port, usb, serial-communication

I am writing an android application and need to write some data to PC's USB port (Windows/Linux) from android application. I've searched a lot and cannot find any clue about how to do this kind of communication.
Is it possible to do this in anyway? Can you suggest me some example or something to help?

Comment: USB is a bus (like PCI), and is not a device.  So a "USB port" is like a PCI slot; if there's nothing installed into the port/slot, then there's no device to control or communicate with.  Hence your question make no sense.  You first need to define/establish a USB connection between USB host (typically a PC) and a USB slave device (aka gadget).  The gadget identifies itself to the host, and the host is expected to install appropriate drivers for applications to access the gadget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem, answer is not that known. In short you must use adb and port forwarding. for more detail you can use this link.
[Connecting android to the pc over usb](http://qtcstation.com/2011/03/connecting-android-to-the-pc-over-usb/) 
hope it works! ;)